# Add listBox Items to int array in visual studio 2016

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, listbox

```
        displayNumbersListBox.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            if (openNumFileDialogBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader ipFile = File.OpenText(openNumFileDialogBox.FileName);
                while (!ipFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    displayNumbersListBox.Items.Add(ipFile.ReadLine());


                }
                int[] number = new int[displayNumbersListBox.Items.Count];
                MessageBox.Show("After loop");
                for(int i=0; i<number.Length; i++)
                {
                    number[i] = int.Parse(displayNumbersListBox.Items[i].ToString());
                }
                prime(number); //a method to put prime numbers in a file
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

In my this code I am adding items in list box from an external file, and then I am adding these elements in an int array, Can someone please help me out what is wrong with this?

Comment: Shouldn't you tell us what's wrong with it?

Comment: So okay, *what's wrong with it? The which I am choosing from open dialog box has all integers value.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what help you are looking for.  Are you getting errors?  An exception?  Which line throws the exception?  Do favor int.TryParse over simply int.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

1. Read the numbers from the file into an int array. (Depends on what data is actually there in the file and also will have to do some sanity checks)
2. Use the same array to fill the list box as well as do the prime number check.

You can use list boxes, addRange to add a list of values in one go.

Comment: The file which I am choosing from open Dialog Box is an integer data file of numbers.txt format.